# Matching two columns from two spreadsheets and grabbing data from one of the spreadsheets

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I need to match values (texts) between two columns on two different spreadsheets.

To make it easy I brought them together into one sheet.

Currently I have Column A, B, C, D, E and F from the second (2nd) sheet pasted into the first (1st) sheet. After Column F, everything is related to the original (1st sheet).

I am trying to match data from Column A (2nd sheet data) to Column G (1st sheet data). If there is a match, I want to grab the entire row/columns related to Column G, in this case the information from the 1st Sheet.
This is the formula I use and it finds the differences between the two columns, but I cannot figure out how to match it to Column G, and obtain the detailed row with it.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A:$A, $G5)=0, "Doesn't Exist", "")
```

Just to note, the two columns being matched have similar data but are scattered.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you mean you want to join row from 2nd sheet to row first sheet. Right?

I dont't understand why you merge data to one sheet. Keep it seperate on two sheets.

If column G 1st sheet and column A 2nd sheet are the same then you can use this to match.

Place formula in column H 1st sheet.
With this formula you wil fetch data from column B 2nd sheet to column H 1st sheet.

`=index(sheet2!B1:B3;match(sheet1!G1;sheet2!A1:A3;0))`

Repeat formula in next columns, I, J, K, L...etc

Comment: Thank you for the information. Ok, I now have two sheets. What I am trying to do is this: Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 share similar data in a column (they are not sorted, some exist, some dont). I am trying to grab a match from the column in the 2nd sheet. If the match is found, copy all the information in that row from sheet two, and place it in sheet 1, next to the match. Almost like updating my sheet 1 with data from sheet 2, but no overiding. I just want the data to be placed on the matched row in Sheet 1.

Comment: Also to mention, the column contains text and numbers

Comment: You have to repeat the formula for each cell off the row.

Comment: Hello, not yet. I am still working on it. I will report back.